# PayPal bearer resets after x amount of seconds

Tags: paypal, credentials, bearer-token, clientcredential

I’m using PayPal refund api. The api docs says the bearer token that I am using will reset after x amount of seconds.

Link to where it says access token resets:
https://developer.paypal.com/reference/get-an-access-token/

In my case my token resets after 9 hours. I am using this token to refund purchases which will happen all the time. Is there an alternate solution from `Bearer <Access-Token>` that doesn’t include a reset token? I haven’t been able to find one other than the `Basic <client_id>:<secret>` which includes client credentials which doesn’t seem to work. And yes the credentials are correct.

Link to api:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_refund

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Basic client_id:secret`, where the string client_id:secret is Base64 encoded, is the header value for HTTP Basic Authentication. This is used to obtain an access token from the oauth2 token endpoint.

Access tokens expire after 9 hours, beyond which a new one must be obtained. These are required for all PayPal REST API operations, including refunds.

Comment: How would I automate this so I don’t have to update my projects code every 9 hours to handle refunds?

Comment: Cache the value. If it is expired, get a new one.

Comment: ok got it. I was using postman to get an access token. The key was to do it directly from python.